# xml data always being created as CDATA and not PCDATA

Tags: c#, xml, soap, xmlwriter, pcdata

I wrote a web service with `C#` , and i want one of his methods to return an XML.
i've managed to do so , but all the data is being tagged as `CDATA` and not being parsed. its not what i am looking for.

**this is my code :**

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true, Description = "Returns the safe activities for the required days period in XML")]
    public string GetSafeActivitiesXML(string safename, int days, string FileName)
    {
        string returnErrorCode = "001";
        try
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
            {
                Indent = true
                //IndentChars = "  ",
                //NewLineChars = "\n",
                //NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None,
                //Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
            };

            StringWriter sb = new StringWriter();
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb,settings);

            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("GetSafeActivitiesResult", "");

            int lineCouner = 0;

            if (safeActivities.Count > 0)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("ListOfStrings", "");
                foreach (ActivityLogRecord activity in safeActivities)
                {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("string");
                        writer.WriteElementString("outFileName", (activity.Info1.Substring(activity.Info1.LastIndexOf("\\")+1)));
                        writer.WriteElementString("activityTmStamp", activity.Time.ToString());
                        writer.WriteElementString("userName", activity.UserName);
                        writer.WriteElementString("ActionID", activityCode);
                        writer.WriteElementString("direction", direction);
                        writer.WriteElementString("path", activity.Info1);
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        lineCouner++;
                    }
                 }
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }

            writer.WriteStartElement("retunCode");
            writer.WriteString((lineCouner > 0) ? "0" : "2");
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteStartElement("retunMessage");
            writer.WriteString((lineCouner > 0) ? "תקין" : "אין נתונים");
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();

            XmlDocument xmlOut = new XmlDocument();

            xmlOut.LoadXml(sb.ToString());
            writer.Close();
            //xmlOut.Save(xxx);
            string finalOutput = sb.ToString();
            finalOutput.Replace("![CDATA[", "").Replace("]]", "");
            return sb.ToString();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.LogWrite("GetSafeActivities", string.Format("Operation has failed: {0}, internal errorcode: {1}", ex.Message,returnErrorCode), Session.SessionID, true);
            return string.Format("<ReturnCode>{0}</ReturnCode><ReturnMSG>{1}</ReturnMSG>", "שגוי", ex.Message) ;             
        }

    }
```

**This is an example for the current output:**

```
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
  <GetSafeActivitiesXMLResponse xmlns="http://www.securenet.co.il">
     <GetSafeActivitiesXMLResult><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
  <GetSafeActivitiesResult>
   <ListOfStrings>
<string>
  <outFileName>code-xmp-tmp.txt</outFileName>
  <activityTmStamp>21/06/2015 10:58:38</activityTmStamp>
  <userName>naaman</userName>
  <ActionID>קובץ אוחסן בכספת</ActionID>
  <direction>Unknown</direction>
  <path>Root\fgdf\code-xmp-tmp.txt</path>
</string>
</ListOfStrings>
<retunCode>0</retunCode>
<retunMessage>תקין</retunMessage>
 </GetSafeActivitiesResult>]]></GetSafeActivitiesXMLResult>
   </GetSafeActivitiesXMLResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

**This is what i want to achieve:**

```
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
  <GetSafeActivitiesXMLResponse xmlns="http://www.securenet.co.il">
     <GetSafeActivitiesXMLResult><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
  <GetSafeActivitiesResult>
   <ListOfStrings>
<string>
  <outFileName>code-xmp-tmp.txt</outFileName>
  <activityTmStamp>21/06/2015 10:58:38</activityTmStamp>
  <userName>naaman</userName>
  <ActionID>קובץ אוחסן בכספת</ActionID>
  <direction>Unknown</direction>
  <path>Root\fgdf\code-xmp-tmp.txt</path>
</string>
</ListOfStrings>
<retunCode>0</retunCode>
<retunMessage>תקין</retunMessage>
 </GetSafeActivitiesResult></GetSafeActivitiesXMLResult>
   </GetSafeActivitiesXMLResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

**so my question really is , how to get rid of the CDATA tag, and why is it there on the first place.**

i'm new to xml, so please be patient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the method returned a String type, and that was the problem. 
i changed the return type to XmlDocument, and now its all honey and nuts.

Answer (score 0):

The output you want to achieve is [XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/) that is not [well-formed](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-well-formed): you're essentially trying to nest an XML document, complete with an [XML declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-XMLDecl) (i.e. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>`), as literal character data within an XML document (or fragment) -- this is not a legal construct.

The proper way to include an XML document, or any text which would be recognized as [markup](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-markup), within another XML document (element) is to basically escape it by using a [`CDATA` section](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-cdata-sect) so that it is **not** parsed as markup. And that is exactly what the web service/SOAP infrastructure is doing for you.

If it didn't do that and your XML text became parsed data (`PCDATA`) like you want, the consuming parser would throw an exception or return an error because your web service response XML would not be well-formed.

Comment: hi, i dont really need this "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>" i just need the structure to be parsable AKA PCDATA, what can i do to achieve that ?